# Issues with inline const System::String

Tags: string, visual-c++, c++-cli, inline

```
namespace Globals
{
    using namespace System;
    public ref class GlobalClass
    {
    public: 
        inline static const String^ File_Path = "Database.xml";
    };
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2022. After creating this in a header file,
I get this error for inline:

```
a nonstatic data member cannot be declared as inline
```

I googled but couldn't find anything specific.

Comment: Try removing `inline` maybe?